# Why does pip install requirements.txt install extra packages?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I have a repository with an inflated requirements.txt file that I'd like to clean up. Using [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs) I've set my requirements.txt to be a minimal set of packages need for my repository. To test this, I setup a virtualenv to install the packages and then run all my unit tests to make sure they're satisfactory.

```
virtualenv temp_venv --no-site-packages
source temp_venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Which runs fine, but I see that a whole bunch of extra packages are collected and installed. Why? Are these identified as needed by required packages, and thus installed? If so, should I then include them in the requirements.txt?

Comment: In order to make sure that the extra packages are really dependencies, try running the command `pip freeze -l > requirements.txt` while in your virtualenv (notice the `-l` flag which makes it only refer to packages in the current virtualenv. If it produces the same output, it's dependencies. If not, that means that pip collected all your packages and not just the ones on your current working virtualenv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The packages are dependencies of your dependencies​.

But no, you should not specify them directly. Automatic tools know to download dependencies recursively and it would significantly add to maintenance overhead.

Answer (score 1):

This might have been because of the dependencies of your written libs in `requirements.txt`. For ex: if you have written `scipy` as requirement `numpy` will also be installed because `scipy` is dependent on `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me the above answers were not the case. Pip install was installing extra packages not in requirements.txt . The solution was:

Run conda create -n venv_name and conda activate venv_name, where venv_name is the name of your virtual environment.

Run conda install pip. This will install pip to your venv directory.

Then run pip install -r requeriments.txt

The above answer was adapted from here: [Using Pip to install packages to Anaconda Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment)