# I am not able to update tensorflow installed with anaconda

Tags: tensorflow, pip, installation

I have been trying to update tensorflow from 1.2.1 to 1.3.
I did the following on my terminal:

```sh
pip3 install tensorflow --upgrade
```

After this, I tried checking the version

```sh
python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
```

This outputs 1.2.1 but not 1.3.0

All this had been done in an anaconda environment.
Operating system: macOS Sierra

I would like to know how one can perform this update.
Thank you

Comment: Try typing `which pip3` and `which python3`. Are they coming from the same distribution?

Comment: @Engineero Also `pip3 --version`

Comment: No, they aren't

Comment: which pip3 outputs

Comment: /usr/local/bin/pip3

which python3 outputs
/Users/SMBP/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/bin/python3

I believe you just solved my problem. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found was to install pip inside the conda environment and use that instance of pip to install the packages. Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment)

The reason I got the above error was that the python3 and pip3 paths were different.

This became evident when I ran the below commands inside the conda environment.

```
which python3
```

/Users/SMBP/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/bin/python3

```
which pip3
```

/usr/local/bin/pip3

Also, I think it is better to use virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper if you wish to work with tensorflow as it is the recommended way.