# How to uninstall package in Anaconda installed with pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

**The problem:**

I have installed Anaconda:

```
conda -V
conda 4.4.7
```

Also I installed a lot of packages for it using `python3 setup.py install`.
I used it for some packages created from `setup.py` files.

Now I want to uninstall one package.

**What I tried:**

```
pip uninstall packageName
pip3 uninstall packageName
conda uninstall packageName
```

It works for python: check `pip list` and `pip3 list` and there isn't such package.

**Error:**

But for conda I got this:

```
conda uninstall packageName
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - packageName
```

Let's check:

```
conda list
packageName
```

P.S. I found info that `conda uninstall` and `conda remove` doesn't work in this case. But what to do then?

P.S.S. Actually I changed real package name at `packageName` but if this information is important I will add it.

---

**My info:**

```
conda info

     active environment : None
       user config file : /home/masamok4/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/masamok4/anaconda3/.condarc
                          /home/masamok4/.condarc
          conda version : 4.4.7
    conda-build version : 3.0.27
         python version : 3.6.3.final.0
       base environment : /home/masamok4/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
          package cache : /home/masamok4/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/masamok4/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/masamok4/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/masamok4/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.4.7 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.3 Linux/4.4.0-87-generic ubuntu/16.04 glibc/2.23
                UID:GID : 1003:1003
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: Um... a little confusing. But `conda` and `pip` have different indexing way. `conda` use a file to record index while `pip` directly scan lib directory. So although `conda list` could show all packages including `pip install`ed. The packages installed by `pip` are out of `conda`'s control.

Comment: @Sraw thank you for response! Ok, I get it, but how then can conda include this packages after I used `pip uninstall`?

Comment: Was this poblem ever solved ?

Comment: @Mihaela I can't say for sure - I reinstalled the entire anaconda, so I can't reproduce this behavior right now

Answer (score 12):

You can use Jupyter Notebook to solve this problem :

- open Jupyter Notebook
- open a new notebook with the right kernel
- type `!pip uninstall -y [package]` in a code cell
- run the cell code

Comment: what does right kernel mean? right environment you mean? or correct python ?

Comment: @agent18 you have to run your notebook after switching to the environment you want to modify

Comment: did this work for you @xiawi ? For me it did not.

Comment: For the answer I proposed (not this one, on which you comment), it consists in listing all the files of the package then delete them. Thus, yes "it works" but there is a risk in terms of dependencies. If, for you, it "does not work", you should ask another question explaining the exact reasons "it does not work" (because it is not obvious at first glance)

Answer (score 12):

Definitely the best way to uninstall all pypi packages in a conda environment is:

```sh
conda activate <your-env>
conda list | awk '/pypi/ {print $1}' | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

Answer (score 2):

One has to be careful when using pip inside a conda environment, whether for installing and unistalling packages. What works for me is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/43729857/1047213.

1. Install `pip` that is specific to the conda environment by running `conda install pip` inside the conda environment.
2. Specify the entire path of that specific `pip` while installing or uninstalling a package. Usually, you will find it inside the `bin` folder of the virtual environment (e.g., `/anaconda/envs/venv_name/bin/`). Thus, the following works for me: `/anaconda/envs/venv_name/bin/pip install_or_uninstall package_name`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I already have no such configuration, so can't check it right now
But will check if face this problem again

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the package using `setup.py`, then you will most likely have to delete the package files manually.

You'd find the [Uninstalling setup.py install](https://ofswiki.org/wiki/Uninstalling_setup.py_install) wiki useful. Unix instructions quoted below:

```
sudo python setup.py install --record files.txt
# inspect files.txt to make sure it looks ok. Then in bash:
tr '\n' '\0' < files.txt | xargs -0 sudo rm -f --
```

Comment: Is there any way to prevent uninstalling the package if other packages depend on it?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not!