# I uninstalled pip by accidentally running `pip uninstall pip`. Now, how to reinstall pip?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I am in a conda virtual environment(windows) using Anaconda prompt.

I have accidentally run

```
pip uninstall pip
```

In order to reinstall it, I have run

```
conda install pip
```

it responds with

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

But if I type `pip`, it says it is not a known command.

How can reinstall pip in this virtual envirmonment?

Comment: You need to create a new virtual environment and then try installing

Comment: You can find more on this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337016/how-to-uninstall-package-in-anaconda-installed-with-pip

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment/43729857#43729857

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by running

```
conda uninstall pip
```

and then

```
conda install pip
```

It *seems* that when pip uninstall itself, it does not accomplish the task completely,
so it can't work, but if you just run

```
conda install pip
```

Anaconda says it is already installed, as some of its files still exist, as probably Anaconda gets them as proof of pip being already installed. That is why one must completely uninstall pip before attempting to reinstall it.

Answer (score -3):

The simplest solution to this would be to uninstall whichever python you have and re install Python 3.4+. This will include pip.