# Uninstall pip and python, to be able to re-install with anaconda. Best practice?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, uninstallation, jupyter-lab

I've installed jupyterlab as suggested here, using pip: https://jupyter.org/install
I ran the code `pip install jupyterlab` No more, no less.

I am experiencing problems, and have decided to delete jupyterlab, pip and python, and re-install it using anaconda:
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-set-up-anaconda-and-jupyter-notebook-the-right-way-de3b7623ea4a

The reason I want to do this switch, is that I've gotten the impression that anaconda is better at managing python installation than pip. I definitely want anaconda to "take over" management of all the important components (python and jupyterlab)

How do I get rid of all the components? I got a recommendation to use this method: [How to uninstall pip on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012597/how-to-uninstall-pip-on-osx)
Which means to run `sudo pip uninstall pip`
According to comments this is the only way, best way and worst way to uninstall pip.
I'm inclined to try, but how do I get rid of all the programs managed by pip?
Specifically, do I need to uninstall jypyterlab? I'd like everything to be managed by anaconda do avoid trouble, but I have some connections to jupyterlab that I'd like to avoid setting up again.

This does seem like an important consideration, to get a stable install ? Here's another guy with this issue:

[How to uninstall package in Anaconda installed with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337016/how-to-uninstall-package-in-anaconda-installed-with-pip)

[What is the easiest way to remove all packages installed by pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248073/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-all-packages-installed-by-pip)

Update: Tried this code

```
pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)
```

This did not get rid of all jupyter directories. I assume what's left is config files that I can just remove.

Comment: Conda will set up its own environment, which should avoid all packages installed before anyway.

Comment: What files are you left with?

Comment: I'd go that way:

    sudo pip uninstall pip

and also would uninstall python and jupyter.

Anaconda would anyway reinstall both from scratch, and you don't want to mess with conda env having to guess, months from now, which files\interpreter etc conda is using among the ones you have.

a little more sweat now, less troubles in the future.

Comment: You no need to uninstall pip and the related python version. You can still simply install Anaconda and it will set up its own environment. I am also using this way.