# jupyter notebook opens even after uninstalling it

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

[image]

I had Jupyter notebook installed in the conda base environment. I need to uninstall Jupyter and reinstall it to fix some errors. However, even after `conda remove jupyter`, it still opens on the command `jupyter notebook`. Any idea how to fully uninstall?

conda list shows:

```
jupyter-events            0.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server            2.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server-fileid     0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server-terminals  0.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server-ydoc       0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-ydoc              0.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab                3.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-server         2.22.0                   pypi_0    pypi
```

i have already tried removing these using `conda remove`:

```
conda remove jupyter-events jupyter-server jupyter-server-fileid jupyter-server-terminals jupyter-server-ydoc jupyter-ydoc jupyterlab jupyterlab-server 
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - jupyter-events
  - jupyter-server
  - jupyter-server-fileid
  - jupyter-server-terminals
  - jupyter-server-ydoc
  - jupyter-ydoc
  - jupyterlab
  - jupyterlab-server
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions here :-

1. You create a new clean conda environment with the required packages, or
2. You can try the command `conda uninstall notebook` (However, you'll need to run it on all packages you want to get rid of as there is no single command for doing what you want.)

Comment: OP already tried the `uninstall` command, but in vein.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. `uninstall` and `remove` have the same functionality. A messy situation is usually caused when you `pip install` inside a conda environment. Maybe this link would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337016/how-to-uninstall-package-in-anaconda-installed-with-pip