# Error installing pyzbar with Conda on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, conda, zbar

I am attempting to convert a project from a Python 3 venv to Conda. However, it doesn't work with Conda, apparently because there is no repository that supports macOS.

This is disappointing because using `brew` and `pip` to install `zbar` and `pyzbar` in the original project works fine. So clearly the files exist but are not available through Conda repos. Am I missing a repo somewhere? If not, is there a way to crowbar the packages downloaded with `pip` and `brew` into a Conda environment?

Here's what I've tried.

I [see instructions](https://anaconda.org/lightsource2-tag/pyzbar) which say to use `conda install -c lightsource2-tag pyzbar`. However Conda fails to resolve (complete error message at the bottom of this note).

This seems consistent with the results of searching https://anaconda.org/search?q=pyzbar . The only repos listed are for Linux and win32.

```
(NewUI_conda) BlueMorph: /Users/Wes 12:16
516$ conda install -c lightsource2-tag pyzbar
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pyzbar

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/lightsource2-tag/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/lightsource2-tag/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like `pyzbar` is not available through Anaconda Cloud channels for **osx-64** platform. Instead, one can (cautiously) mix PyPI and Conda packages. For example, a basic YAML definition would be something like:

**zbar_env.yaml**

```
name: zbar_env
channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
dependencies:
 - python=3
 - zbar
 - pip
 - pip:
   - pyzbar
```

which can be instantiated with:

```
conda env create -f zbar_env.yaml
```

As per [the recommendations for mixing PyPI and Conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env), place all requirements in this YAML file from the start. If you need to add something new, edit the YAML and recreate the env.

---

Alternatively, you could switch to `zbarlight`, [which is available through Conda Forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/zbarlight) and appears to be consistently maintained.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this could work so I checked it. For my immediate needs I simply installed pyzbar using pip from within the conda env and used brew to install zbar.

However, when I get to the place where I want to package this up, I will try the custom formula you provided. Thanks!