# How to install a package in Python

Tags: python, package, anaconda

I would like to install the package : newsapi in Python

I run the command

```
pip3 install newsapi-python
```

The package was succefully installed. But I import him in Anaconda :

```
from newsapi import NewsApiClient
>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'newsapi'
```

I would like to know how to solve this kind of problem. I think that is linked to some path, but I am not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're installing packages with anaconda, you'll want to use 
`conda install newsapi-python` instead of pip. Pip is the default package manager for python.

Comment: However this package does not exist in conda :

Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - newsapi-python

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment) link is probably what you're looking for then.

Answer (score 0):

You have the package, your Anaconda interpreter just doesn't know where it is. The easiest way to fix this is to just reinstall using the `--user` flag. By default, Anaconda will pull in your user packages.

Try `pip3 install newsapi-python --user`, and then see if you can import it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
python3 -m pip install newsapi-python
```