# How do I install textfsm in python?

Tags: python, windows, installation

Context: Windows 7, spyder with python 3.6 and anaconda.

Can't find `textfsm` on anaconda.org.

Can find `textfsm` in pypi - https://pypi.org/project/textfsm/#files

Can download `textfsm-0.4.1.tar.gz` and extract to textfsm-0.4.1

Do I put it in C:...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages?

What next?

Comment: Do you have pip? You can just use `pip install textfsm`

Comment: I keep reading somewhere - don't use pip with anaconda

Answer (score 0):

Proceed to unpacked folder and run

```
python setup.py
```

Usually it is all what you need in this case. It should does all necessary things by itself if you have already installed all dependencies.

You should also consider to use pip for package manipulation. In 3.6 it is ready from box. 
But if it is not, just refer to https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/ and follow instructions.

Comment: ok. I ran 'pip install textfsm' inside an anaconda prompt. This seemed to create a folder - textfsm-0.4.1.dist-info inside Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages and created/uploaded some files - texttable.py,textfsm.py,terminal.py,copyable_regex_object.py,clitable.py in Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages - prompt said errors on twisted 17.5.0 has requirement automat 0.3.0 but I have 0.0.0 which is incompatible. Still, it installed testfsm 0.4.1 - got help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment -

Comment: I must have misunderstood the Spyder intro panel which says 'It seems that you are using Spyder with Anaconda/ 
Miniconda. Please don't use pip to update it as that will probably break your 
installation.'  That seems pip for spyder and not the other packages installed with pip.