# How do I allow pip inside anaconda3 venv when pip set to require virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I've just rebuilt my mac environment using the tutorials here:

https://hackercodex.com/guide/mac-development-configuration/ & here: https://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/

I want to require a virtualenv for pip, and have set that by opening:

`vim ~/Library/Application\ Support/pip/pip.conf`

and adding:

```
[install]
require-virtualenv = true

[uninstall]
require-virtualenv = true
```

Then, I followed a guide to set up jupyter notebooks w/tensorflow, because I am trying to follow a udemy course on machine learning that requires both: https://medium.com/@margaretmz/anaconda-jupyter-notebook-tensorflow-and-keras-b91f381405f8

During this tutorial, it mentions that you should use pip install instead of conda install for tensorflow, because the conda package isn't officially supported.

I can install pip on conda just fine by running:

```
conda install pip
```

But when I try to run:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

I get the error:

"Could not find an activated virtualenv (required)."

I know why I'm getting this error, I just don't know how to change my code to ALSO accept use of pip & pip3 inside anaconda venvs.

My anaconda3 folder is inside my Virtualenvs folder, along with all of my other virtual environments.

I've tried temporarily turning off the restriction by defining a new function in ~/.bashrc:

```
cpip(){
PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="0" pip3 "$@"
}
```

and using that instead, with no luck, not surprisingly.

I think the problem may be here, inside my bash_profile:

```
# How to Set Up Mac For Dev:
# https://hackercodex.com/guide/mac-development-configuration/
# Ensure user-installed binaries take precedence
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
# Load .bashrc if it exists
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc


# Activate Bash Completion:
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    source $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi


# Toggle for installing global packages:
gpip(){
   PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="0" pip3 "$@"
}
# Toggle for installing conda packages:
cpip(){
   PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="0" pip3 "$@"
}
# Be sure to run "source ~/.bash_profile after toggle for changes to
take effect.
# Run "gpip install" (i.e. "gpip install --upgrade pip setuptools
wheel virtualenv")


# added by Anaconda3 2018.12 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false
'/Users/erikhayton/Virtualenvs/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook
2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f
"/Users/erikhayton/Virtualenvs/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ];
then
        .
"/Users/erikhayton/Virtualenvs/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export
PATH="/Users/erikhayton/Virtualenvs/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

I want to be able to use pip (& pip3, pip2) in both (& only in) anaconda3's activated 'env's
and virtualenvs.

Answer (score 2):

When you `conda install pip` , a new pip is placed inside your anaconda virtualenv's `bin/` directory. Each pip knows whether/which virtualenv it's inside of, and each pip only installs packages inside its own virtualenv. You can run it like `/Users/erikhayton/Virtualenvs/anaconda3/bin/pip install tenserflow`

You can know where `pip3` is by running `which pip3`.

When you `activate` a virtualenv, environment variables in your shell are being modified. The virtualenv's `bin/` directory is placed in your `PATH`. If you run `/Users/erikhayton/Virtualenvs/anaconda3/bin/activate` and then `which pip3`, you'll see a different path.

See also [Using Pip to install packages to Anaconda Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment)

Comment: Solid response. running "which pip3" is helpful, but let me clarify my problem a bit. I can get a virtualenv activated, and I can activate a jupyter notebook if I'm in my base path, or if I create a env inside anaconda3. My problem is, I'm trying to force pip to install only when a virtualenv is present, but it won't work with anaconda's venv's. How do I make it work with both?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `pip` doesn't recognise the conda environment as being not the global environment. It [doesn't look like the `pip` authors intend to fix this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4367) (for good reasons I think btw). On the `conda` side there seems to be no movement either (considering [this github issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10787) that has not seen any movement over the past year). So basically, we'll have to do our own scripting :).

This means that whenever we activate a `conda` environment, we either need to make it look like we're also in a virtual environment, or we switch off `PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV`. The solution below uses the latter option (but I can imagine the former working just as well). There is unfortunately no global `activate` hook in `conda`, but there are [per environment hooks](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables). So all we need to do is run the following 2 commands in our environment:

```bash
    echo "export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=false" > "$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/dont-require-venv-for-pip.sh"
    echo "export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true" > "$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/deactivate.d/require-venv-for-pip.sh"
```

Now whenever we activate this `conda` environment, `PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV` will be set to `false`, and it will be reset to `true` as soon as wel deactivate the environment.

Since we want to (easily) install this is into all our environments, I made a function which I placed in my `.zshrc` (should work just as well in your `.bashrc`/`bash_profile`).

```bash
function allow_pip_in_conda_environment() {
    # abort if we're not in a conda env (or in the base environment)
    if [[ -z "$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV"  || "$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV" == "base" ]]; then
        echo "Should be run from within a conda environment (not base)"
        return
    fi
    ACTIVATE="$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/dont-require-venv-for-pip.sh"
    DEACTIVATE="$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/deactivate.d/require-venv-for-pip.sh"

    # abort if either the activate or the deactivate hook already exists in this env
    if [[ -f "$ACTIVATE" || -f "$DEACTIVATE" ]]; then
        echo "This hook is already installed in this conda environment"
        return
    fi

    # write the hooks (create dirs if they don't exist)
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$ACTIVATE")"
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$DEACTIVATE")"
    echo "export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=false" > "$ACTIVATE"
    echo "export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true" > "$DEACTIVATE"

    # switch off PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV in the current session as well
    export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=false
}
```

Now every time I run into a dreaded `Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).`, all I need to do is run `allow_pip_in_conda_environment`, and it fixes it in my current session, and forever after in this `conda` environment.

(PS: same code also works with mamba)

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you use virtual environments, you need to `activate` them first before you can use them. Somewhere along the line, you would have needed to run a command to create your virtual environment:

```
virtualenv awesome_virtualenv
```

Then to make it active:

```
cd ~/Virtualenvs/awesome_virtualenv
source bin/activate
pip3 install tensorflow  # this will install TensorFlow into your awesome_virtualenv
```

You can create as many virtual environments as you want and install different sets of libraries in each.

Comment: I forgot to add that step to the question. I did activate the virtual environments within anaconda, but am still unable to do a "pip install".