# Python If I should use pip/pip3 to install/update packages when anaconda is my python organizer?

Tags: python

I was informed that if I have installed anaconda to organize python then I would better install using:

```
conda install mypackage
```

rather than

```
pip3 install mypackage
```

Is that true? if that is true, can anyone tell some reason for that? version inconsistent or hard to maintain?

Answer (score 1):

You can install your packages with both `conda` and `pip`, all of them would work well. The only difference is that `conda` is Anaconda's package manager, while pip is Python package manager, so there could be some version incompabilities between the packages, installed from different packages into one virtual environment.

Comment: how to use pip to install packages into virtual environment? it always goes to some systematic folders, not my virtual folder, by default

Comment: there is an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are some difference here:

conda install will install package in your venv environment when you are install under some environment.which may be some thing like: d:/.../venv

while

pip install will install package in some system folder, in my computer is like c:/users/.../

you can definitely change the order of the path in your sys.path to decide which version of package you can use, if you have more than one version installed(if you install numpy 
 using both conda install and pip install then you may get two versions in two different folders)

There may be some way to put the installed package from pip also in venv folder, I am trying to find it.