# Pip is not recognized in command prompt bu working in Anaconda prompt

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, command-prompt, conda

I know if I add `pip` path to env variables, this would resolve. But I am not able to find the directory where `pip.exe` is located.

Attached are the snapshots of working in `Anaconda prompt` but not working in `command prompt`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add it in your path `<path to python>/python/scripts`

Comment: @anand_v.singh my question is not about to add path. I know that already. Question is find the path of pip which I am unable to locate because I am using Anaconda so there is no external directory like `Python34` as we normally see.

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment

Comment: That's not what I am finding. `pip` is running on my Anaconda Prompt but not running on command prompt of windows.

Comment: That is because pip is not added to path as I earlier said, check out the system variables and in that check path.

Comment: `where /r "C:" pip.exe` may show it to you.

Answer (score -1):

Add pip path to your environmental variables.

```
My Computer->Properties->Advanced system settings-> environment variables -> edit path 
variable in in the system variables box then append your path with it
```

Comment: my question was different. I have resolved that issue but problem is here I am getting downvoting on this question so I want to delete this question and for that I need your favour to delete your reply because stackoverflow does't allow to delete question that already has answer.