# How to install PyVimeo for Python 3.7?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, vimeo

I'm trying to install PyVimeo for Python 3.7 in Windows.
I keep getting this error in my command terminal when trying a Pip install.

```
C:\Users\my_name\Downloads>C:/Users/my_name/Anaconda3/Scripts/pip install PyVimeo-1.0.11.tar.gz --user

Processing c:\users\my_name\downloads\pyvimeo-1.0.11.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.4.0 in c:\users\my_name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from PyVimeo==1.0.11) (2.24.0)
Collecting tuspy==0.2.1
  Using cached tuspy-0.2.1.tar.gz (9.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\my_name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.4.0->PyVimeo==1.0.11) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\my_name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.4.0->PyVimeo==1.0.11) (1.25.8)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\my_name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.4.0->PyVimeo==1.0.11) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\my_name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.4.0->PyVimeo==1.0.11) (2019.11.28)
Collecting pycurl==7.43.0
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz (182 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\my_name\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ndtvvoaz\\pycurl\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\my_name\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ndtvvoaz\\pycurl\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\my_name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ndtvvoaz\pycurl\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\my_name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ndtvvoaz\pycurl\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I've downloaded the PyVimeo file from here.
https://pypi.org/project/PyVimeo/
And went over various solutions from both StackOverFlow and github, but to no avail.
Any help in solving this is very much appreciated.

Possible solutions from github
https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.py/issues/129
from StackoverFlow
[Use PyVimeo from Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54722116/use-pyvimeo-from-anaconda)

I've installed the latest version of setuptools.

UPDATE:
pip install PyVimeo --no-dependencies
This worked, but when I do
`import vimeo`
I get this error for tusclient, but I can't do a `pip install tusclient`
Here is the error message Module Not Found Error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-4cf9739b0a3e> in <module>
----> 1 import vimeo

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vimeo\__init__.py in <module>
      6 version = (0, 3, 10)
      7 
----> 8 from .client import VimeoClient
      9 from . import exceptions

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vimeo\client.py in <module>
      9 from .auth.client_credentials import ClientCredentialsMixin
     10 from .auth.authorization_code import AuthorizationCodeMixin
---> 11 from .upload import UploadMixin
     12 from .exceptions import APIRateLimitExceededFailure
     13 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vimeo\upload.py in <module>
      8 import requests.exceptions
      9 from . import exceptions
---> 10 from tusclient import client
     11 
     12 try:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tusclient'
```

UPDATE 2:
Okay, so I did `pip install tuspy`.
So now I can do `import vimeo` without any error.
However, when I do `pip install tuspy`, I get this error message.

```
ERROR: pyvimeo 1.0.11 has requirement tuspy==0.2.1, but you'll have tuspy 0.2.4 which is incompatible.
```

So not sure this is going to actually work.
When I tried `pip install tuspy==0.2.1`, I get the pycurl error at the top.
Real hassle.

Answer (score 0):

In your jupyter notebook
type `!pip3 install PyVimeo --user`

Comment: Hi Qbert, thanks for the possible solution, but it didn't work when I tried `pip install PyVimeo --user`. Got the same error above. I can't do `pip3`, don't have that option. I uninstalled Anaconda, then re-installed it. Still stuck :(

Comment: In anaconda navigator, their is an option for environments try to search pyvimeo there