# gTTS package installation using anaconda on windows

Tags: windows, anaconda, gtts

I am creating my own chatbot and so I need the gTTS package but I can not install it with conda on windows, every time the installation ends with a failure.

I tried:
`conda install gTTS`

and also:
conda `install -c conda-forge gTTS`

The result:

```
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - gtts

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - ....
  - ....

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: Apparently nobody has packaged it yet. That leaves you following options: 1) install it with pip 2) contribute it to conda-forge here: https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes

Answer (score 1):

Official Anaconda Cloud gives solution

```
conda install -c tdido gtts-token
```

Reference URL : https://anaconda.org/tdido/gtts-token

This works on Python3.4

Answer (score 0):

On the anaconda website, it says that gtts is only available for download on Linux, so I don't think you can use gtts with conda on Windows.
https://anaconda.org/tdido/gtts-token

You have the option of using Linux, or installing from pip. https://pypi.org/project/gTTS/

What you could do is install pip in your conda virtual environment. However, using pip and conda together might cause problems, so it is best to create a new conda virtual environment if possible to install pip and gtts.

1. Create a virtual environment using `conda create --name pip_env`
2. Open it using `conda activate pip_env` of `source activate pip_env`
3. In a new virtual environment, use `conda install pip` to install pip
4. Then use `pip install gtts`
5. To double-check that it has been installed, use `conda list` in pip_env to look for gtts.

Info about conda with pip: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment

Info about managing packages in python (with conda and pip): https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html

Installing pip and other pip modules in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43729857/14171363