# shared condaenv for multiple users on Windows

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, azure-data-factory

### Current Unexpected Behavior

We have a computer with multiple (auto)users. (on Microsoft Azure).
If we try to use `pip install` on a conda environment that was created by an other user, we get a "Access is denied" error.

### Steps to Reproduce

We have installed anaconda as admin using following command:

```
C:\Windows\Temp\Anaconda3.exe /InstallationType=AllUsers /AddToPath=1 /RegisterPython=1 /S
```

If I create a condaenv using one user, lets say**_azbatchtask_20**, we are able to activate it, install packages inside, and deactivate it:

```
conda create -p D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users python=3.7 -y
conda activate D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users
pip install see
deactivate
```

However if we now login under **_azbatchtask_21**, and try install new packages in this same environment, we get weird error "Acess is denied":

```
conda activate D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users
```

works, but:

```
pip install nltk

> Access is denied
```

In case useful, we checked permissions of the newly created condaenv folder using

```
    icacls D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users

    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
    ae0f56229000000\_azbatch:(I)(F)
    ae0f56229000000\_azbatch:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
    ae0f56229000000\WATASK_COMMON_GROUP:(I)(F)
    ae0f56229000000\WATASK_COMMON_GROUP:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(F)
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
```

We also tried to grant full permission to everyone using following command (but `pip install` still fails after that)

```
icacls D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users /grant "Everyone:(OI)(CI)F" /T
```

### Environment Information

`conda info`

```
     active environment : D:\batch\tasks\shared\ChinaPortWeather22_condavenv37
    active env location : D:\batch\tasks\shared\ChinaPortWeather22_condavenv37
            shell level : 1
       user config file : D:\Users\_azbatchtask_74\.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.6.11
    conda-build version : 3.17.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          D:\Users\_azbatchtask_74\.conda\pkgs
                          D:\Users\_azbatchtask_74\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : D:\Users\_azbatchtask_74\.conda\envs
                          C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          D:\Users\_azbatchtask_74\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.11 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.14393
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

`conda list --show-channel-urls`

```
# packages in environment at D:\batch\tasks\shared\ChinaPortWeather22_condavenv37:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ca-certificates           2019.5.15                     0    defaults
certifi                   2019.3.9                 py37_0    defaults
openssl                   1.1.1c               he774522_1    defaults
pip                       19.1.1                   py37_0    defaults
python                    3.7.3                h8c8aaf0_1    defaults
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0    defaults
sqlite                    3.28.0               he774522_0    defaults
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4    defaults
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_4    defaults
wheel                     0.33.4                   py37_0    defaults
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0    defaults
```

EDIT 27th JUNE: I noticed that there is no `/bin/` folder inside the created conda environment, as it should be as explaned in documentation here

Find below the structure I have

```
Directory of D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users

06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          .
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ..
04/20/2018  01:28 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:28 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:28 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:28 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:29 PM            22,280 api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            21,256 api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            20,744 api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,184 api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            20,744 api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            22,792 api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            20,744 api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            27,912 api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            26,888 api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            71,432 api-ms-win-crt-private-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            23,304 api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            24,840 api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            24,840 api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            21,256 api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           329,368 concrt140.dll
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          conda-meta
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          DLLs
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          include
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          Lib
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          Library
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          libs
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            12,769 LICENSE_PYTHON.txt
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           625,808 msvcp140.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM            31,896 msvcp140_1.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           195,248 msvcp140_2.dll
04/24/2019  08:30 PM            95,232 python.exe
04/24/2019  08:30 PM           438,272 python.pdb
04/24/2019  08:30 PM            51,712 python3.dll
04/24/2019  08:30 PM         3,745,792 python37.dll
04/24/2019  08:30 PM         9,523,200 python37.pdb
04/24/2019  08:30 PM            93,696 pythonw.exe
04/24/2019  08:30 PM           438,272 pythonw.pdb
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          Scripts
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          tcl
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          Tools
04/20/2018  01:37 PM         1,016,584 ucrtbase.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           386,720 vccorlib140.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           155,280 vcomp140.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM            87,200 vcruntime140.dll
              56 File(s)     18,091,625 bytes
              11 Dir(s)  69,282,779,136 bytes free
"\Lib" 
 Volume in drive D is Temporary Storage
 Volume Serial Number is 2AF3-E29E

 Directory of D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users\Lib

06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          .
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ..
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,580 abc.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            32,814 aifc.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM               477 antigravity.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            95,103 argparse.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            12,575 ast.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            11,328 asynchat.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          asyncio
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            20,118 asyncore.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            20,380 base64.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            31,489 bdb.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            13,954 binhex.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             2,557 bisect.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            12,410 bz2.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            24,826 calendar.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            34,549 cgi.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            12,018 cgitb.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,435 chunk.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            14,860 cmd.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            10,619 code.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            36,287 codecs.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,994 codeop.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          collections
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             4,064 colorsys.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            13,649 compileall.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          concurrent
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            54,283 configparser.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            23,774 contextlib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM               129 contextvars.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             8,815 copy.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,017 copyreg.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,805 cProfile.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             3,346 crypt.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            16,180 csv.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ctypes
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          curses
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            48,508 dataclasses.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            86,298 datetime.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          dbm
03/25/2019  08:21 PM               320 decimal.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            84,387 difflib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            19,888 dis.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          distutils
03/25/2019  08:21 PM           104,284 doctest.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             2,815 dummy_threading.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          email
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          encodings
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ensurepip
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            34,778 enum.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             9,830 filecmp.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            14,568 fileinput.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             4,056 fnmatch.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            15,143 formatter.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            23,639 fractions.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            35,257 ftplib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            32,441 functools.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             4,756 genericpath.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,489 getopt.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,994 getpass.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            21,967 gettext.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,638 glob.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            20,338 gzip.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             9,534 hashlib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            23,017 heapq.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             6,517 hmac.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          html
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          http
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          idlelib
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            53,292 imaplib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             3,795 imghdr.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            10,536 imp.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          importlib
03/25/2019  08:21 PM           117,615 inspect.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             3,517 io.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            75,072 ipaddress.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          json
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             2,245 keyword.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          lib2to3
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,312 linecache.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            78,027 locale.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          logging
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            12,983 lzma.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             6,123 macpath.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            78,654 mailbox.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             8,104 mailcap.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            20,880 mimetypes.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            23,035 modulefinder.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          msilib
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          multiprocessing
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,566 netrc.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            43,088 nntplib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            22,340 ntpath.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             2,584 nturl2path.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            10,244 numbers.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,824 opcode.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            10,863 operator.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            60,371 optparse.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            37,756 os.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            49,389 pathlib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            62,544 pdb.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            57,837 pickle.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            91,220 pickletools.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             8,916 pipes.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            21,461 pkgutil.py
04/24/2019  07:46 PM            47,067 platform.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            29,885 plistlib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            14,964 poplib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            15,772 posixpath.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            20,884 pprint.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            22,046 profile.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            27,313 pstats.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             4,763 pty.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            15,137 pyclbr.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM           106,731 pydoc.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          pydoc_data
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             8,001 py_compile.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            11,359 queue.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,254 quopri.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            27,557 random.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            15,192 re.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,267 reprlib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,097 rlcompleter.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            11,959 runpy.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             6,442 sched.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             2,038 secrets.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            18,561 selectors.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             8,527 shelve.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            12,956 shlex.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            41,329 shutil.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             2,123 signal.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          site-packages
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            21,649 site.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            34,711 smtpd.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            44,210 smtplib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,086 sndhdr.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            27,363 socket.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            26,922 socketserver.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          sqlite3
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            26,872 sre_compile.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,177 sre_constants.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            39,305 sre_parse.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            45,432 ssl.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,038 stat.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            20,651 statistics.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            11,564 string.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            12,917 stringprep.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM               257 struct.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            69,966 subprocess.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            18,375 sunau.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             2,131 symbol.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,274 symtable.py
04/24/2019  07:46 PM            24,649 sysconfig.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            24,317 sysconfig.py.orig
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            11,408 tabnanny.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            92,617 tarfile.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            23,135 telnetlib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            26,710 tempfile.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          test
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            19,494 textwrap.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             1,003 this.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            48,104 threading.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            13,444 timeit.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          tkinter
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             3,763 token.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            27,030 tokenize.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            28,543 trace.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            23,438 traceback.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            17,076 tracemalloc.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM               879 tty.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM           143,602 turtle.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          turtledemo
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             9,897 types.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            54,602 typing.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          unittest
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          urllib
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             6,816 uu.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            29,449 uuid.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          venv
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            20,242 warnings.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            18,229 wave.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            20,689 weakref.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            23,097 webbrowser.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          wsgiref
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,913 xdrlib.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          xml
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          xmlrpc
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,535 zipapp.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            80,379 zipfile.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             1,801 _bootlocale.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            26,424 _collections_abc.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             8,749 _compat_pickle.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,340 _compression.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,117 _dummy_thread.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            14,598 _markupbase.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            19,138 _osx_support.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM           228,535 _pydecimal.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            91,166 _pyio.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             6,186 _py_abc.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             3,115 _sitebuiltins.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            25,504 _strptime.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,214 _threading_local.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,679 _weakrefset.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,101 __future__.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM                64 __phello__.foo.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          __pycache__
             172 File(s)      4,330,005 bytes
              34 Dir(s)  69,282,762,752 bytes free
"\Lib\site-packages" 
 Volume in drive D is Temporary Storage
 Volume Serial Number is 2AF3-E29E

 Directory of D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users\Lib\site-packages

06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          .
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ..
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          certifi
06/20/2019  10:54 PM             2,990 certifi-2019.06.16-py3.7.egg-info
04/23/2019  01:18 AM               126 easy_install.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          pip
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          pip-19.1.1-py3.7.egg-info
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          pkg_resources
03/25/2019  08:21 PM               119 README.txt
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          setuptools
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          setuptools-41.0.1-py3.7.egg-info
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          wheel
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          wheel-0.33.4-py3.7.egg-info
06/28/2018  10:27 PM             5,788 wincertstore-0.2-py3.7.egg-info
10/23/2013  07:30 AM            11,873 wincertstore.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          __pycache__
               5 File(s)         20,896 bytes
              11 Dir(s)  69,282,762,752 bytes free
```

"\Library" 
     Volume in drive D is Temporary Storage
     Volume Serial Number is 2AF3-E29E

```
 Directory of D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users\Library

06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          .
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ..
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          bin
05/29/2019  06:11 PM               412 ct_log_list.cnf
05/29/2019  06:11 PM               412 ct_log_list.cnf.dist
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          include
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          lib
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          misc
05/29/2019  06:11 PM            10,909 openssl.cnf
05/29/2019  06:11 PM            10,909 openssl.cnf.dist
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ssl
               4 File(s)         22,642 bytes
               7 Dir(s)  69,282,762,752 bytes free
"\Library\bin" 
 Volume in drive D is Temporary Storage
 Volume Serial Number is 2AF3-E29E

 Directory of D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users\Library\bin

06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          .
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ..
04/20/2018  01:28 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:28 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:28 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:28 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:29 PM            22,280 api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            21,256 api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            20,744 api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,184 api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            20,744 api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            22,792 api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            20,744 api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            27,912 api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            26,888 api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            71,432 api-ms-win-crt-private-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            23,304 api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            24,840 api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            24,840 api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            21,256 api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           329,368 concrt140.dll
06/27/2019  04:29 AM             6,548 c_rehash.pl
05/29/2019  06:11 PM         3,407,360 libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
05/29/2019  06:11 PM        10,088,448 libcrypto-1_1-x64.pdb
05/29/2019  06:11 PM           681,472 libssl-1_1-x64.dll
05/29/2019  06:11 PM         2,322,432 libssl-1_1-x64.pdb
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           625,808 msvcp140.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM            31,896 msvcp140_1.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           195,248 msvcp140_2.dll
05/29/2019  06:11 PM           542,720 openssl.exe
05/29/2019  06:11 PM         2,527,232 openssl.pdb
04/22/2019  06:33 PM         1,028,608 sqlite3.dll
04/22/2019  06:33 PM         1,303,552 sqlite3.exe
04/20/2018  01:37 PM         1,016,584 ucrtbase.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           386,720 vccorlib140.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           155,280 vcomp140.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM            87,200 vcruntime140.dll
              57 File(s)     25,601,052 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  69,282,762,752 bytes free
 Volume in drive D is Temporary Storage
 Volume Serial Number is 2AF3-E29E

 Directory of D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users\libs

06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          .
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ..
04/24/2019  08:30 PM           170,564 python3.lib
04/24/2019  08:29 PM           342,616 python37.lib
04/24/2019  08:30 PM             1,750 _tkinter.lib
               3 File(s)        514,930 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  69,282,762,752 bytes free
```

Comment: Honestly, I have no clue about Anaconda but python in general. Which directory the `pip install` wants to access? Did you tried `pip install --user` to install the package for the user? (just for debug purposes)

Comment: What happens when you try to use conda to install NLTK?  `conda install nltk -n test-condaenv-users`

Answer (score 5):

It sure looks like pip tries to install packages globally instead of inside the environment, so I've compiled a list of approaches you might want to try to force local pip usage:

- Install pip during environment creation:

```
conda create -p D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users python=3.7 pip
```

- Install pip after environment creation (local pip will supposedly take effect after you deactivate and reactivate environment):

```
conda create -p D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users python=3.7
conda activate D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users
conda install pip
conda deactivate
```

- Call local pip explicitly:

```
conda activate D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users
D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users\bin\pip install nltk
```

**Reading list**:

- [Using Pip to install packages to Anaconda Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment)
- https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1429

Hope it helps.

Comment: indeed that helps. I was able to notice now that I have no `/bin/` folder in this environment, even if I specify that I wish to install both python and pip: `conda create -p D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users python=3.7 pip`. I added in the question the structure of my environment folder.

Comment: any idea why /bin/ would be missing or why my folder structure is different from standard conda env?
before activating environment,  `where pip` gives `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe`. After activating it it gives `D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users\Scripts\pip.exe` AND `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe`

Comment: Finally I tried `D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users\Scripts\pip.exe install nltk` which returns "Access is denied"

Comment: Ok, I have just reproduced your setup (Windows Server 2016). Got the exact same `conda info` output, directory structure (so no worries about the missing /bin folder), `where pip` results, etc. And one of my non-administrative (a member of Users and Remote Desktop Users) guys has successfully created the environment, while the other one has activated and performed `pip install nltk`.

I've tried stuff to force pip "access is denied" me: enabled SmartScreen, tried to lock files, etc. but no success. Both of my users were able to activate the environment and install whatever they wanted.

Comment: Say, is the OS image you have deployed your VM a standard one? Was it customized in any way? Policies applied? Antivirus installed?

Could you try to search for open handles in the environment folder? You could use Process Explorer for it.