# Conda ObjectPath Installation is not working

Tags: installation, conda, objectpath

I tried installing objectpath in Conda promt using

```
    conda install -c auto objectpath
```

but this does not install saying packages not found. I used the code in the https://anaconda.org/auto/objectpath.

I have a doubt whether there is a new command, because this code was uploaded 5 years ago.

please clarify my doubt. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed it! What I did was installed ObjectPath package using pip command.

First check if you want to add your package to your default environment. If you want to create new one please check this:[Using Pip to install packages to Anaconda Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment)

I wanted to add the package to my default. So:

1. I first activated my environment using the command

> ```
>  conda activate<environment name>
> ```

2. Install pips

> conda install pip

3. now type in pip commands you want. (for me it was ObjectPath)

> pip install ObjectPath

4. Check whether the package is being installed in your desired environment.

> conda list

Main concern is the environment you are trying to install this. Activate the desired one.

Thanks! Hope this will help someone who has/will face the same problem as I did :)