# Do these commands do the same action?

Tags: python, pip, conda

Basically I would like to know if those 2 snippets do the same thing :

```
conda install -n myEnv myPackage
```

VS

```
conda activate myEnv
pip install myPackage
```

Or in a different way, does a `pip install` when a conda environment is activated equal doing a `conda install` on myEnv ?

EDIT : I thought it was obvious but => more precisely, does the second snippet only install the package on the environment or on the overall system ?

PS : Asking because there's a package available with pip but not with conda and I want it to only be installed on myEnv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Pip to install packages to Anaconda Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment)

Comment: @Mohan the suggested duplicate has many rather confusing answers - I think this is a simpler question which can be answered much more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

The [Anaconda docs](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) make it clear that if you use `conda` as your virtual environment manager, you should stick to `conda install` to install new packages as far as possible:

> Unfortunately, issues can arise when conda and pip are used together
>   to create an environment, especially when the tools are used
>   back-to-back multiple times, establishing a state that can be hard to
>   reproduce. … Running conda after pip has the potential to
>   overwrite and potentially break packages installed via pip. Similarly,
>   pip may upgrade or remove a package which a conda-installed package
>   requires.

If you can't get all the packages you need from a conda channel, they say this, which is good advice even if you don't use pip:

> If there is an expectation to install software using pip along-side
>   conda packages it is a good practice to do this installation into a
>   purpose-built conda environment to protect other environments from any
>   modifications that pip might make.

Finally the same document notes:

> Use conda environments for isolation
>
> - create a conda environment to isolate any changes pip makes
> - environments take up little space thanks to hard links
> - care should be taken to avoid running pip in the “root” environment

Provided you `activate` the correct conda environment first, the `pip install` command(s) should use that environment's `pip` and install only into that environment.

Comment: You are not answering my question at all. I'm aware of best practices in programming. I made this post precisely for this purpose.

The second text you are quoting is exactly the root of my concern. There's a package (`pdf2image`) which I can't install with `conda`, but is possible to install with `pip`. However I only want it to be installed on the virtual env, hence why I'm asking this question here to know if doing a `pip install` when a conda env is activated only installs it on the given environment and not on the system itself.

Comment: See my edit (and read the linked doc all the way to the end ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.
`pip` downloads and installs the package from PyPI whereas `conda` does the same from Anaconda repositories.
There are packages in `PyPI` not present in Anaconda, and the other way around.
For managing the environment I would choose one way or the other, since with pip you can freeze into a requirements.txt (`pip freeze > requirements.txt`) and conda you can either export the whole environment (`conda env export`) or the list of packages (`conda list --export > requirements.txt`). However if you try to use a conda-generated file from pip, it will most probably fail.

Comment: I want to install a package in a conda env but which is not available with conda, hence my question. Does pip always install system-wide or only in the currently activated environment ?

Comment: In that case you have to install pip in your environment (`(env) conda install pip`), then use it to install whatever packages you need. Doublecheck with `pip -V` to show if you're invoking global/env pip or `pip list -v` to show where the packages are being installed.