# Anaconda env is using another env's site package

Tags: python, anaconda

I have Anaconda 1.9.7 installed on Mac 10.14.16. I encountered a strange behaviour when a new env is installed. `which python` show the correct python path, but the site-packages are linked to another environment, so when I use `pip install` it tries to put the package into another environment's site-package.

I have no idea why this happens. Not sure if I accidentally changed the bash_profile.

This code looks ok:

```
# added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Have you got a PYTHON_PATH environment variable being set somewhere? That can cause issues. Just try `echo $PYTHON_PATH` before activating a conda environment to check.

Comment: Hi, I tried echo $PYTHON_PATH but nothing is printed. and which python pointed to  //anaconda3/bin/python

Comment: Hmm, looks like `PYTHON_PATH` is not the culprit then. Have a look at what pip is being used with `which pip`.

Comment: which pip showed: //anaconda3/bin/pip. Then this is what is shown on a new env called test_pyaudio, when I pip install PyAudio. It tells me I already has PyAudio at another env called pya:  (test_pyaudio)  ~  $ which pip
//anaconda3/envs/test_pyaudio/bin/pip
(test_pyaudio)  ~  $ pip install pyaudio
Requirement already satisfied: pyaudio in /anaconda3/envs/pya/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.2.11)

Comment: I've realised my comment above should have been `echo $PYTHONPATH` without the underscore. Try that and see it you see anything, which seems to have been the issue in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Pip to install packages to Anaconda Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment)