# How to make conda recognize pip installed python packages?

Tags: pip, conda

I have created a conda environnmennt
and then pip installed tensorflow using a pip wheel. numpy was installed by pip at same stage.

When trying to install scipy,
conda wants to install numpy in parallel of pip installed numpy....?

How to make various installed be recognized by conda ?

Comment: maybe this one helps: https://github.com/sagemathinc/cocalc/issues/2403

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [the new configuration option `pip_interop_enabled`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/pip-interoperability.html), introduced in Conda v4.6 is for. It is still considered a "preview" feature, but I've had success using it:

```
 conda config --set pip_interop_enabled true
```

Until this feature is released in earnest, I think it would be wise to limit its use to a per-env-basis by using the `--env` flag when running the above.

It should be kept in mind that preferring Conda packages is still best practice. A must read in this regard is "[*Using Pip in a Conda Environment*](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)".

Comment: conda insall tends to be HEAVIER in size thant PIP Install.
for quick testing, pip looks better...

Comment: @tensor yes, because Conda packages tend to supply the full chain of dependencies (arguably better for reproducibility across systems), whereas PyPI packages have historically been Python-only (though wheels bundled with non-Python dependencies are becoming more common).