# Mark package as manually installed in anaconda virtualenv (miniconda)

Tags: python, pip, conda, miniconda

I've had to install a package with pip in a conda environment to get it to work for my application ([link](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/1956#issuecomment-597291343)).
The package works fine. However, every time I modify the virtual environment in any way, conda tries to install the "missing" package - which would effectively result in downgrading it.

Question: is there a way to mark the pip package as 'manually installed' in the conda venv (e.g. in the same way [apt-mark](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt-mark.8.html) would handle it)? The intention is to get miniconda to leave it alone while still handling the remaining dependencies for the desired additional package.

The pip installed package indeed shows up when typing `conda list`, with Channel "pypi".
Can give any additional information if needed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make conda recognize pip installed python packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58888125/how-to-make-conda-recognize-pip-installed-python-packages)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried but at every install command, conda tries to install older versions of packages that I installed with pip. As of now, I'm forced to install each package with --no-deps flag, with the effect of excluding all needed dependencies. It's alright but I'd rather let conda take care of it *except* for specific given packages.

Comment: Sounds like you could [add package pinning](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#id10) to this.

Comment: That solved it, thank you @merv