# what where and how of pip when mixed with virtual environments

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda

What i think i know currently is this:

1. The way to install pip is `sudo apt-get install python-pip`
2. `sudo apt-get install python-pip` installs pip at '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'
3. `pip install abc` installs abc to virtualenv where pip that gets called is

I use conda, and i have an environment 'env' created with it for some time now. I needed to install a package that said i needed pip3 > 19.0.1 so i `which pip` and it was 9.0.2 and it was well within the environment. i updated the pip using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and it got upgraded to 20.0.2. I am happy. However, `which pip3` gives me global location, version 9.0.2 and the package i am going to be installing requires `pip3 install ..`  command and `conda install pip3` doesn't exist

questions:

1. How do i install pip3 in a conda environment?
2. Supposing i did not have `conda install pip` or let us say i had a non conda virtualenv created, how do i go about installing a pip in this environment so that `pip install ...` does not install to global location?

Comment: was the virtual environment `env` created with python 2 or with python 3?

Comment: Look this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment

Comment: Conda doesn't use the aliases `pip3` or `pip2`, instead just activate the environment and use `pip`. Also, please read the documentation ["Using Pip in a Conda Environment"](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env) to familiarize oneself with the problems it can cause. I strongly recommend against using Pip in the **base** environment.