# Geonamescache installation in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, geonames

I am new at this and I wonder why I cannot install or import geonamescache library in anaconda.

Apparently, I am the only one among my friends with this problem. Could you help me?
Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCI4g.png)

Comment: Is your jupyter notebook using python 3? Try importing in the regular python repl.

Comment: _I cannot install or import geonamescache library in anaconda._ Look at the path of the Python installation in the error message. Be careful when you're using pip, see https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: I am using Python 3.7 for Mac OS. Sorry for sharing images I did not know how to put the output to show it. THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using conda you should make sure you jupyter notebook is either installed in the same conda environment containing `geonamescache` or has its kernel pointed to that environment. Check the output `conda list` in your activated environment for the said package. If you don't find it (I'm expecting you won't) it means `pip3` installed `geonamescache` as a system wide package. You'll need to install it your activated environment using `pip install geonamescache`. Try not to use the `pip3` command in conda environments.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I installed from Jupiter notebook. Thank u so much !!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what OS and version of Anaconda you are using, so I can't be very specific.

According to the official list of packages for the distribution of Anaconda 3.7 for Mac OS(I am currently using it), there are currently 657 packages supported by anaconda(For Windows that number stands at around 620 at the moment). [Here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs/) is the full list for up-to-date distributions.

I have looked into `geonamescache`, and it looks like it might not be supported by Anaconda at all. I suggest you looking into installing it via Pip(keep in mind that I would do that only if necessary as it is better to avoid using Pip with Conda that much). Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment) if interested.

Comment: I am using I dowloaded Anaconda 2020.02 for Mac OS. Python version 3.7. When I use "pip install geonamescache" it says it does not find pip command. So, I used "pip3 install geonamescache --user" then it says is installed, but when I import it does not work.