# Problem importing modul OpenCV in Anaconda

Tags: python, module, opencv

I am a beginner in terms of using python. Currently, I got python 3.7 and I am using anaconda as IDE. For my project, I need to detect the location and brightness of points/dots in an external imported picture. I figure I could use the modul OpenCV. Unfortunately, I am stuck right now with the problem to import the module cv2. I already successfully installed the package using

```
python -m pip install OpenCV-python
```

on command prompt. OpenCV  Version which was installed is 4.2.0.34. While compiling the test script of OpenCV on Spyder

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```

I got this message

```
"ImportError : DLL load failed : The Modul was not found."
```

Can somebody let me know please how to fix this problem? Is somehow the version of OpenCV I got not compatible with the Python version? I already watched and followed many tutorial videos on Youtube, but I couldn't find the solution. I tried to copy the cv2.pyd to the site-packages folder in

```
C:/user/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages directory
```

still it didn't fix the problem...

I would appreciate any answers and help I could get here. Thank you!

Comment: Are you on the correct virtual environment? Have you created a virtual environment other than `base`? To see a list of enviroments use `conda info --envs` in terminal, and you should read this to understand conda/enviroments better. [link](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#viewing-a-list-of-your-environments)

Comment: i never changed the environment, or create one. On the list of the environments, there's no opencv or cv2.

Answer (score 1):

try installing it using these commands in the following order:

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update navigator-updater
pip install opencv-python
```

It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try `conda install opencv`
or `conda install -c menpo opencv`

Comment: i tried both commands on Anaconda prompt. still didn't work :(

Comment: Did you activate your environment? Otherwise you can also install with pip, though should only be used as last resort in a conda environment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment