# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras' Can't import keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have tried reinstalling anaconda. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling keras.
I have tensorflow 2.3.0  and keras 2.4.3 installed. But I just can't seem to be able to import keras.
This is my import statement.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from pandas import DataFrame, concat
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
```

And I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

I also tried installing them in different anaconda environments but it just doesn't seem to work. I am trying to make a deep learning model. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try 'from tensorflow import keras' ?

Answer (score 1):

With tensorflow 2.X keras is a part of tensorflow

maybe try:

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

and remove keras
Its not so good too run keras and tensorflow in one enviroment

Comment: I tried doing that. It's showing "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
" even though I have tensorflow version tensorflow  2.3.0 installed.

Comment: does it work with other packages ? What OS you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

I would first like to ask you whether only Tensorflow/Keras is broken.

An obvious reason for a `ModuleNotFoundError` problem is that Keras is not reachable by Python library lookups. Although this is a common problem everybody has experienced, the primary solution is simple.

You can check installed packages in the command prompt by `pip freeze`. If you are sure installed the package, you must add the full directory of libraries to the PATH variable. Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages) on how to add to the PATH variable.

In case you already done that, and doesn't solve your problem, refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment),

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend running the following pip commands:

```
pip install tensorflow
pip install keras
```

If it says they are already installed, add `--upgrade` to the end of the line.
If you are using a notebook, replace `pip` with `!pip`.

Then using the following imports:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
#Other imports
```