# How to install a package only within a conda environment, without affecting other environments?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, virtual-environment

I thought that this would simply be done by running `pip install` within the environment (after `source activate`). But in my case, `pip install` affects ALL my environments.

For example, I am trying to install an older version of torch only in `env1`, but if I run  `pip install torch==1.1.0` after `source activate env1` all my environments have torch version 1.1.0.

I also tried manually running `pip` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment)
but it didn't work.

How can I fix that?

Versions

- Anaconda 3, 2019.07
- Python 3.7

Comment: Is something in your PATH making pip executable not the one for the environment? What if you use `python -m pip install`

Comment: @OneCricketeer Same results, all torch versions are updated/downgraded (depending on which I install).
`$PATH` outputs
`/private/home/username/.conda/envs/ride/bin:/public/apps/anaconda3/2019.07/condabin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: No such file or directory`

Comment: I also tried manually running `pip` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment)
but it didn't work.

Comment: Wow, that's really strange.  If this were happening to me, I'd want to figure out what is actually changing on my filesystem when I install a package.  You ought to be able to do this and see that the new files are going to one of your Python installs and not a venv.  If you do see files within a venv directory changing, and that affects anything else, something is super wacko.

Comment: I'd say remove Anaconda from your path, then install pyenv and use it for version management and just virtualenv itself for environments unless you explicitly need conda