# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pdftotext: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, cmd, conda, pdftotext

I installed installed `pdftotext` module as

1. `conda install -c conda-forge poppler`
2. `pip install pdftotext` (I also tried `pip install pdftotext==2.1.5`), but it still triggers an error when I try to import it, abeit being installed successfully:

   `import pdftotext`

ERROR:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pdftotext: The specified module could not be found.
```

IDK what else to do; so, your help will be really appreciated:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and noticed that `pdftotext` wasn't listed in `conda list`. [As it turned out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment), simply running `pip install pdftotext` inside a new environment installs pdftotext as a system-wide package, but not as a specific package for your current conda enviroment.

I fixed this problem by installing pip into my conda environment using the following command:

`conda install pip`

After that, I ran `pip install pdftotext==2.1.4` (as the 2.1.5 version didn't work for me).
Lastly, I checked `conda list` to verify the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have had the same question. I have solved it by

1. conda update conda .

Then I redo the same procedure

2. conda install -c conda-forge poppler
3. pip install pdftotext

After this 3 steps I import successfully pdftotext.  I hope it also works for you.