# Unable to import a package that seems to have been installed

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to work with the TimeSynth Python package in my Conda environment. It is not available on the pkgs list or conda-forge list of Conda-supported packages, so I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment) that seems to get around the issue by installing the package in the Conda environment using `pip`.

I followed the instructions in the accepted answer, however when I do the last step:

```
.conda/envs/tcl/bin/pip install timesynth
```

(**tcl** is the name of my environment)

It says the requirement is already satisfied:

> Requirement already satisfied: timesynth in
> ./.conda/envs/tcl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.2.4)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: scipy in
> ./.conda/envs/tcl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from timesynth) (1.4.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: jitcxde-common==1.4.1 in
> ./.conda/envs/tcl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from timesynth) (1.4.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: numpy in
> ./.conda/envs/tcl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from timesynth)
> (1.18.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: sympy in
> ./.conda/envs/tcl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from timesynth) (1.8)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: symengine==0.4 in
> ./.conda/envs/tcl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from timesynth) (0.4.0)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: jitcdde==1.4 in
> ./.conda/envs/tcl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from timesynth) (1.4.0)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in
> ./.conda/envs/tcl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from
> jitcxde-common==1.4.1->timesynth) (3.0.0a1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in
> ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from
> jitcxde-common==1.4.1->timesynth) (56.2.0)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=1.1 in
> ./.conda/envs/tcl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from
> jinja2->jitcxde-common==1.4.1->timesynth) (2.0.0)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in
> ./.conda/envs/tcl/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from sympy->timesynth)
> (1.2.1)

However when I run a Python script that imports timesynth, it doesn't recognize the module. Any advice?

EDIT:
Per request, here is the start of the file I'm trying to use timesynth in:

```
import numpy as np
import TimeSynth.timesynth as ts
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
```

And the error cites line 2 and states:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TimeSynth'

Comment: have you tried to run a pip3 install of the module?

Comment: Please add commands and output to your question. Though it seems trivial, we don’t know for sure your import statement is correct or whether you properly activated the environment.

Comment: @smitty_werbenjagermanjensen I just tried that, and it said the requirements were already satisfied.

Comment: Seeing the import, looks like a typo. Should be `import timesynth as ts`, at least that's how [the library's example imports](https://github.com/TimeSynth/TimeSynth/blob/master/TimeSynthExamples.ipynb).

Comment: Maybe you are not running the "good" python... Try to run with .conda/envs/tcl/bin/python

Comment: @Addison i think you should look at merv's answer

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes @merv was correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [the TimeSynth library's example](https://github.com/TimeSynth/TimeSynth/blob/master/TimeSynthExamples.ipynb), the import statement of OP

```
import TimeSynth.timesynth as ts
```

should instead be

```
import timesynth as ts
```