# How to use Tensorflow Hub Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-hub

**GOAL** to use a pre trained model from a TensorFlow [example project](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/style_transfer) more specifically [Tensorflow hub](https://tfhub.dev/google/magenta/arbitrary-image-stylization-v1-256/2)

1.

- To do that am trying to install `tensorflow_hub` with the following command: `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-hub`
- `conda list`  OUTPUT: .... tensorflow-hub            0.12.0             pyhca92ed8_0    conda-forge  ....
- To a sagemenaker EC2 instance's anaconda environment.
- The whole installation process runs thru without any error, but when I am trying to import the package it act like it is not installed `import tensorflow_hub as hub`
- ERROR

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-5c017171c13e> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow_hub as hub

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_hub'
```

2. 

- I have manually downloaded the model and uploaded to the ec2 but I don't know how to load it in and use it

3. Adding with pip tensorflow_hub
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/43729857/10270590

```
1. Run `conda create -n venv_name` and `source activate venv_name`, where `venv_name` is the name of your virtual environment. 

2. Run `conda install pip`. This will install pip to your venv directory. 

3. Find your anaconda directory, and find the actual venv folder. It should be somewhere like `/anaconda/envs/venv_name/`. 

4. Install new packages by doing `/anaconda/envs/venv_name/bin/pip install package_name`.
```

OUTPUT

```
(tf2p37) ubuntu@ip:~/anaconda3/envs/tf2p37/bin$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow-hub
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-hub in /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tf2p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.8.0 in /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tf2p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow-hub) (3.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12.0 in /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tf2p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow-hub) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tf2p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from protobuf>=3.8.0->tensorflow-hub) (1.15.0)
```

- it is ther but it still don't want to get imported when I execute : `import tensorflow_hub as hub`

Comment: 1) Please try installing(then importing) the latest versions of tensorflow2.x and tensorflow-hub in a fresh anaconda virtual environment after opening a new notebook in sagemaker(newly created kernel) using the commands below:-

a)!pip install --upgrade tensorflow
b)!pip install --upgrade tensorflow_hub
c)import tensorflow as tf
d)import tensorflow_hub as hub





2)for loading the model through hub, please use:

hub_model = hub.load('https://tfhub.dev/google/magenta/arbitrary-image-stylization-v1-256/2')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I just installed from the Jupiter notebook
- `pip install --upgrade tensorflow_hub`
- this did not overwrite all the other files somehow.
- The base environment was a SageMaker `conda_tensorflow2_p36`
- you can activate it as `conda activate tensorflow2_p36`

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution**:

You can try installing ***tensorflow_hub*** directly into the Python environment used by Jupyter Notebook.

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow_hub
```

or you can install it in your environment using the following code:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow_hub
```

**Second Solution**:

If this also does not work, which usually happens when you are working in the Jupyter notebook, then run the following code:

```
import sys 
!{sys.executable} -m pip install tensorflow_hub
```

This will install tensorflow_hub directly into the Python environment used by Jupyter Notebook.