# Running pip install twice to see changes ("developer mode") -- second install fails but first works

Tags: python, c++, pip, pybind11

I am wondering how to use pip to develop a Python package which is going through many revisions rapidly. My work flow is to write C++ code, compile and install with `pip install` and test my code.

Then, I would like to change some underlying C++ code, recompile and reinstall with pip, test the new feature, change something else, go back etc. until my package is ready.

Why did `pip install ./cmake_example` work well the first time but when making changes to the code, reinstalling with recompiling produced an error? I just re-ran the command `pip install ./cmake_example`.

I changed a single line of C++ code in an innocuous way (adding +1 in the 'add' function just to see if I can change code and recompile) and the code compiled fine in my IDE without pip.

My basic idea was to use `pip` following [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment) to avoid having to hackishly insert my shared object into some python directory each time I make a change.

I used the cmake_example from pybind [here](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example) and followed the steps and did `pip install ./cmake_example` and it worked very well. I ran the example fine in a Python console.

Then, I changed some code (just added +1 to the adding function), so nothing substantial and wanted to `re-install` the package.

I then got this error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: cmake-example
  Building wheel for cmake-example (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for cmake-example (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [65 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
        Running

         '/tmp/pip-build-env-q_8_pyjk/overlay/bin/ninja' '--version'

        failed with:

         No such file or directory
```

and

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cmake-example, which is required to
install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have tried `pip uninstall cmake_example` and then reinstall but to no avail. The `upgrade` function did not work either. Does pip change something in the project folder?

PS: The makers of pybind11 also provide a scikit example [here](https://github.com/pybind/scikit_build_example) where removing the cache for repeated builds is not necessary. The `cmake_example` seems to be intended for legacy projects that do not use the cmake extension scikit. So if the structure of the `cmake_example` is essential to the project, removal of the cache is the only way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that deleting the `build` directory inside the `cmake_example` directory resolved the problem and `pip install ./cmake_example` worked again as it did the first time. You can combine the two commands:

```sh
rm -rf ./cmake_example/build && pip install ./cmake_example
```

---

Looking a little closer, (for me) it was sufficient to delete `cmake_example/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/CMakeCache.txt`. I suspect the lines

```
//Program used to build from build.ninja files.
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=/tmp/pip-build-env-yqopewjn/overlay/bin/ninja
```

inside `CMakeCache.txt` mean that `cmake` caches the path to the ninja executable, but the second time around the temporary path is different, so it can no longer be found where `cmake` expects it.

Comment: Thank you so much @BurningKarl that did do the trick. I considered the 'editable' option but I think that is more geared towards Python only projects.