# Why is pip installing package when already in (conda) environment?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, conda, rdkit

I have a conda environment that contains a package rdkit.
conda list shows it is indeed installed:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
mordred                   1.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
rdkit                     2022.09.1        py39h6c30a6c_1    conda-forge
```

I also have my own package which has in the setup.py (a.o.) rdkit as dependency:

```
    install_requires=[
        'rdkit',
        'mordred'
        ]
```

Unfortunately, when I run `pip install -e .` in the folder of that setup.py, `pip` decides to install `rdkit` again. Now I have two installations of rdkit which is ofcourse asking for trouble. In both cases, it installs `rdkit 2022.09.1`. If I remove `rdkit` from the `install_requires` list everything works fine (even though the package `mordred` has `rdkit` as its dependency). removing mordred, but keeping rdkit makes pip install rdkit again (which it shouldn't because the requirement is already satisfied)

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56889729/7207930

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Pip to install packages to Anaconda Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment)

Comment: Unfortunately, using Python -m pip install . yields the same problem of installing rdkit again (while it is already in the finds env)

Comment: Did you figure this out yet? The [rdkit tag at MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdkit) has 95.5% of its questions answered. If you want this question migrated there, please ping me by typing @Nike in a comment and letting me know. I'll make a case to the moderators for a migration.

Comment: @Nike No I haven't. If you think they can help me with this issue, please migrate this question.

Comment: Actually it's too late. There's a 90-day limit for migrations. You'll have to ask separately on MMSE (you can provide a link to this question in the new question).