# Install Google Maps 4.7 on Conda Environment

Tags: python, google-maps, conda, environment

I would like to to install the latest Google Maps (Version 4.7 as of today) in a `conda` environment.
The question is, how to do it in the configuration file (The `YAML` file) which defines the environment without using the command line

I tried looking for the latest version of Google Maps on `conda-forge`. Yet it is of the 2.x branch.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74370044) for [Using Pip to install packages to Anaconda Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment) you may do something like:

```yaml
name: YourName
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.11
  - numpy
  - scipy
  - pip
  - pip:
    - googlemaps==4.7
```