# ImportError: cannot import name 'where' from 'certifi' (unknown location)

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

a few days that I am strugguling with jupyter not being launched from anaconda prompt.

Not sure what information would be useful to request help.
I created a venv name finance. Installed all the required librairies.

```
(finance) C:\myDrive\Python\Trading\Finance>jupyter notebook
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\notebook\app.py", line 17, in <module>
    from jupyterlab.commands import (  # type:ignore
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .handlers.announcements import (
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\handlers\announcements.py", line 15, in <module>
    from jupyterlab_server.translation_utils import translator
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .app import LabServerApp
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\app.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .handlers import LabConfig, add_handlers
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\handlers.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .listings_handler import ListingsHandler, fetch_listings
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\listings_handler.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 147, in <module>
    from . import packages, utils
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\requests\certs.py", line 14, in <module>
    from certifi import where
ImportError: cannot import name 'where' from 'certifi' (unknown location)
```

When creating the environment I used the command

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

and I had this unusual message.

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\jupyter_contrib_core\notebook_compat\nbextensions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.extensions import BaseExtensionApp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.extensions'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\jupyter_contrib_core\notebook_compat\nbextensions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from notebook.nbextensions import BaseNBExtensionApp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.nbextensions'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\jupyter_contrib_core\notebook_compat\nbextensions.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._compat.nbextensions import BaseNBExtensionApp
  File "C:\Programming\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\jupyter_contrib_core\notebook_compat\_compat\nbextensions.py", line 35, in <module>
    from notebook.nbextensions import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.nbextensions'

done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(952): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::jupyter_highlight_selected_word-0.2.0-py38haa244fe_1005'.
Rolling back transaction: /
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the same issue, but I was getting a similar error and fixed it by installing requests with pip (using the method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43729857/8633026)

Comment: I solved the issue using now jupyter lab

Answer (score 0):

Your **requests** package is most likely out of date and trying to import something from **certifi** that no longer exists (version mismatch).  Try upgrading with:

```
conda update requests
```

Or for **pip** users:

```
pip3 install --upgrade requests
```