# anaconda install modules ttkbootstrap and/or Customtkinter

Tags: python, anaconda, customtkinter, ttkbootstrap

There is a way to install [Customtkinter](https://pypi.org/project/customtkinter/0.3/) or [ttkbootstrap](https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in Anaconda environment?

I didn't find any useful links nor find such packages.
Thank you.

If not, there are some useful tkinter modules which can be installed by anaconda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also unable to find the packages on Anaconda, but I think you should be able work around it by installing these packages via pip using the process detailed here
[Using Pip to install packages to Anaconda Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment)

Comment: It's worth mentioning:


"Only after conda has been used to install as many packages as possible should pip be used to install any remaining software. If modifications are needed to the environment, it is best to create a new environment rather than running conda after pip."


See [this link](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment) for further details.